# Is it a good sign when a potential employer asked me to contact current team members after interviewing for an un-posted job

Tags: interviewing

A few days ago, I had an interview for a job that was not posted online. I got the interview opportunity thanks to my friend's referral. If I were hired, the interviewer would be my direct boss (so he wasn't an HR person).

After the interview, which I think went very well, the interviewer asked me to email him some references. He said he would contact them and would ask the HR office to post the job online because the company regulations dictate that a new job must be posted for an X amount of time. Interestingly (I think), he also asked me to email his current team members for any questions I might have regarding their work, work environment, etc.

I wonder if this is a good sign.

Comment: It isn't a bad sign. You haven't lost the opportunity yet. I don't think any further conclusions are possible; this may simply have been courtesy.

Answer (score 3):

Go with the flow. You haven't been turned down. In fact, they are checking your references. However, as far you getting the job, as Yogi Berra said "it's not over until it's over" and you have the offer in hand.